# Profile Edit doesn't accept a text input as a date

Tags: php, symfony, datetime, fosuserbundle

I'm using Symfony 2 and FOS User Bundle to create a website that handles user information.
I tried to create the edit page to change an existing profile.
My problem is that I want the birthdate to be an input text (because I'm using a Jquery Datapicker). It perfectly works on my register page but when I try to do the same for the profile/edit page, I have a 500 error saying "The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class DateTime. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "DateTime" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class DateTime to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.".

Here is how I wrote my User (User.php entity) birthdate parameter:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="birthdate", type="date")
 * @Assert\NotBlank(groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
protected $birthdate;
```

In my RegistrationFormType.php (that is working fine):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    ...
    $builder->add('givenname');
    $builder->add('familyname');
    $builder->add('birthdate', 'text');
    ...
}
```

When I try to copy paste this code, I got an error. 
The only solution is to do the following:

```
$builder->add('birthdate', 'date', array('input'  => 'datetime'));
```

This solution does work but is not what I want (it generates three select inputs, I would rather have a text input that uses my Jquery datepicker with my Jquery validation).

Do you have any idea why my error occurs on the edit page and not on the registration page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to set the [widget](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#widget) option of your [date field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html) to `text`. It's by default set to `choice`.

**From the documentation:** 
*`text`: renders a three field input of type text (month, day, year).*

**Example,**

```
$builder->add('birthdate', 'date', array(
    'input'  => 'datetime',
    'widget' => 'text'
));
```

---

You can also set it to `single_text`, which allows you to validate the user's input based on the `format` option.

**Example,**

```
$builder->add('birthdate', 'date', array(
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    // this is actually the default format for single_text
    'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
));
```

To let it work through a Date Picker, you've then to add the right class to your field.

Comment: Thank you very much.
In the end, I end up using the second solution (using the single_text widget) so that my date picker could work. The problem is that it is doubled on Chrome (that also have a datepicker for the input date). 
The reason why I didn't get any problem with the registration form is that it doesn't have any value. My getter returns a DateTime object which means that when the profile is updated, the value it receives is a DateTime and not a string (as I would have wanted).